# python: check file extension and prompt again input if invalid file extension

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x, input

**problem**

Doing a while loop to validate file extension. If a file extension is not .exe or .bat, ask user input again. I am looking for a solution without using `import` `endswith` `break` functions.

**code**

```
format = " "
while file[:-4] != ".bat" and file[:-4] != ".exe":
    format = input("Enter file you like to open: ")
    if format[:-4] == ".bat" or format[:-4] == ".exe":
        callFunction(format)
    else:
        file = input("Enter file you like to open: ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop

```
def ask_exe(prompt='Executable file name? '):
    name = input(prompt)
    if name[-4:] in {'.exe', '.bat'}: return name
    return ask_exe(prompt='The name has to end in ".exe" or ".bat", please retry: ')
```

[no breaks, no imports, almost no code...]

As noted by [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) my code, that uses `set` notation for the membership test, is suboptimal for Python versions prior to 3.2.  For these older versions using a `tuple` avoids computing the set at runtime, each and every time the function is executed.

```
...
    # for python < 3.2
    if name[-4:] in ('.exe', '.bat'): return name
...
```

Comment: @ShadowRanger Your edit was a source of inspiration. tx

Comment: Just a heads up, the set literal approach will cost more on older Python; `tuple`s of literals get cached in the per function constant store in all versions of Python, but [membership tests for set literals are only converted to `frozenset`s and stored in the constant store on Python 3.2+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations); on 3.1 and earlier (including all 2.x releases), the `set` has to be built every time, then a membership test is performed; saving on the lookup by rebuilding the `set` every time is a net loss. For two elements, the `tuple` is fine even in 3.2+.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for the interest, the discussion and the link. Now the reason of your edit are really clear. I've edited my answer accordingly (well, I hope so...)

Answer (score 3):

To follow [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) and using [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to extract the file extension:

```
import os

ALLOWED_EXTENSTIONS = {".bat", ".exe"}
while True:
    filename = input("Enter file you like to open: ")
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if extension in ALLOWED_EXTENSTIONS:
        break

with open(filename) as f:
    # do smth with f
```

---

Without `break`:

```
import os

ALLOWED_EXTENSTIONS = {".bat", ".exe"}
extension = None
while extension not in ALLOWED_EXTENSTIONS:
    filename = input("Enter file you like to open: ")
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]

with open(filename) as f:
    # do smth with f
```

---

Without `break` and without any imports:

```
ALLOWED_EXTENSTIONS = (".bat", ".exe")
filename = ""
while not filename.endswith(ALLOWED_EXTENSTIONS):
    filename = input("Enter file you like to open: ")

with open(filename) as f:
    # do smth with f
```

---

Without `break` and without any imports and without `endswith()`:

```
ALLOWED_EXTENSTIONS = {"bat", "exe"}
filename = ""
while filename.rsplit(".",1)[-1] not in ALLOWED_EXTENSTIONS:
    filename = input("Enter file you like to open: ")

with open(filename) as f:
    # do smth with f
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but i was looking for a solution without using endswith and break.

Comment: @LearnAndLearn sure, `endswith()` was extra, fixed.

Comment: is there another way to stop the loop without using break and importing

Comment: @LearnAndLearn updated with an option without `break`.

Comment: haven't learn the import yet, is there a solution without using import?

Comment: @LearnAndLearn updated, without break and without any imports.

Comment: thanks for the help but i'm still not getting the solution i am asking, as i've mentioned in my post. i am avoiding `break` `import` `endswith`

Comment: @LearnAndLearn http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire. Though, I would say, in this case, it's probably me not reading the question and the limitations carefully. Hope it is good now.

Comment: I think you want `filename.split(".")[-1]`, you could also `filename.rsplit(".",1)[-1]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ah yeah, messed things up, thanks for noticing!